# Rest client with bad response

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a REST client with powershell, actually It's almost done but I have a little problem with the response from the API

So here is how I am invoking it

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $newUri -Method Get -ContentType $content -Headers $headers |Out-Host
```

and what I get as response is:

```
statusCode     : 200
startIndex     : 0
itemsPerPage   : 1
totalResults   : 1
filtered       : False
sorted         : False
entry          : *{@{data=}}*
serverMessages :
```

This *{@{data=}}* should be a JSON output something like this:

```
entry: [
-{
-data: {
allowedCommentsEndTime: 0
-alternateIds: [
-{
name: "smtp.messageId"
```

and more....

How can I GET the whole thing or access it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = (Invoke-RestMethod -uri $newUri -Method Get 
        -ContentType $content -Headers $headers).data
```

Your data will be assigned to *$data* var:

```
$data
```